# clock simultaneous exhibition

Tags: chess-clocks, simultaneous

In a clock simultaneous exhibition, would the exhibitor normally be given extra time to compensate for his/her walking time from board to board? The question was prompted by a scene in a movie (the "Lewis" mystery series) where the exhibitor would come to each board with the opponent's move already having been made and the exhibitor's clock running, make her move and then hit the clock and move on.  Although I realize there's a skill discrepancy, it would still seem to be a distinct disadvantage to the exhibitor otherwise, particularly in a large exhibition.  I have never seen or participated in a clock "simul" myself, which must be relatively rare.

Answer (score 4):

The exhibitor usually gets more time. Not really to compensate for the time walking from board to board takes, but because he potentially has all of the clocks running at the same time!

The most famous clock simultaneous exhibitions were the ones in which Kasparov took on national teams, including those of the Czech Republic and Israel. According to [this old Chessbase article](http://en.chessbase.com/post/is-garry-kasparov-out-of-his-mind-), Kasparov had three hours for 50 moves and the Czech GMs two and a half hours per 50 moves, with half an hour added after 50 moves (he won this 5.5-2.5 over two days).

Usually the difference is larger, but I can't find a source.